# Submit hidden fields in a html form

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a basic HTML form, I would like to seperate the form into three tabs, each tab will contain certain fields, and when submit the form I wish all data in the three forms will be able to submit.

So I have a menu created by `<ul>` and `<li`>

```
<ul class="subnav">
    <li class="subnav0 current"><a href="javascript:showTab('tab1');">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="subnav1"><a href="javascript:showTab('tab2');">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class="lastItem subnav2"><a href="javascript:showTab('tab3');">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and below this menu, I have three divs that represent each of the tab:

```
<div class="tab1"></div>
<div class="tab2 displayNone"></div>
<div class="tab3 displayNone"></div>
```

The input controls elements will be put into each of the tab divs. And the javascript in the menu nav bar will control which tab to display by call `show()` & `hide()` method of each div. (Using jQuery).

Now my problem is:

1) I want to be able to submit the whole form (all controls within three divs). However, html forms won't submit input controls within a displayNone div, which means I will only be able to submit the data within the tab which I am currently viewing but not the other two tabs.

2) I also want to do some javascript functions on hide elements when initialize the form in tab2 or tab3. However, since they are display:none, the javascript will not have any effect.

So is there any way that I can somehow hide the div, but also be able to submit the form and do any javascript operation on it?

Comment: Please Try with jQuery UI Tabs plugin : http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Thanks @diEcho, I know there is such a jQuery plugin, but I guess I am more happy to know if there is a solution for my scenario rather than relying on a library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) display:none controls may still be sent to the server, as they are considered successsful controls

> 17.13.2 Successful controls
>
> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> - If a form contains    more than one submit button, only the activated
>     submit button is    successful.
> - All "on" checkboxes may be
>     successful.
> - For radio buttons    that share the same value of
>     the name attribute, only the "on" radio    button may be
>     successful.
> - For menus, the control name is provided by    a
>     SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only   
>     selected options may be successful.
> - When no options are
>     selected, the    control is not successful and neither the name nor
>     any values are    submitted to the server when the form is
>     submitted.
> - The current value    of a file select is a list of
>     one or more file names. Upon submission    of the form, the contents
>     of each file are submitted with the rest of    the form data. The file
>     contents are packaged according to the form's    content
>     type.
> - The current value of an object control is determined by
>     the object's implementation.

If a control doesn't have a current value

> when the form is submitted, user agents are not required to treat it
>   as a successful control.
>
> Furthermore, user agents should not consider the following controls
>   successful:
>
> Reset buttons. OBJECT elements whose declare attribute has been set.
>   Hidden controls and controls that are not rendered because of style
>   sheet settings may still be successful.

For example:

```
<FORM action="..." method="post">
<P>
<INPUT type="password" style="display:none"  
          name="invisible-password"
          value="mypassword">
</FORM>
```

> will still cause a value to be paired with the name
>   "invisible-password" and submitted with the form.

In any case if that doesnt seem to be working why not try jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) on each form and concatenate the values and ajax them back to the server.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have mixed the concept of disabled and hidden. A quick googling tells me only disabled fields will not be submitted.

Answer (score 3):

On your first point, just because an input is display none, doesn't mean that it will not submit those fields.

On your second point, I don't quite follow.  Are you saying that when you open one of the tabs, you want to do some action on the content?  If so, then JQuery UI allows you to do this:-

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show

Can you give a more complete example, including the form tag and some inputs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yep, indeed my problem on point one. On point 2, I have a workaround is do the js operations first, and then hide the divs, which is working ok.